# Create MySQL event with a dynamic event name

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures

I have to write a stored procedure in which a event needs to be created. Since the stored procedure call depends on the action triggered, a different name needs to be given to the event created.

```
CREATE EVENT variable
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    DO
    Insert into dummy ('abc');
```

The variable name needs to be a dynamic variable, however mysql doesnt let me do that from a stored procedure. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **not possible** in MySQL, this:

```
PREPARE stmt_name FROM CONCAT(CREATE EVENT ",@variable
    ,"ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE "
    ,"DO Insert into dummy (test) VALUES (?);"

SET @test_parm = "abc";

EXECUTE stmt_name USING @test_parm;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
```

Doesn't work because you cannot do that in a prepared statement.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Are you sure create event can be run using prepare? I tried the same and I got the error 'This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet'. And I guess the documents also say prepare statement is restricted to a certain set of DML's only.

Comment: @Maxim, you are right, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html